# Как искать в переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`a = "1055Q999"` как в данной переменной найти `"Q"`?

Comment: Что значит найти??? Поиск тут, кстати, не в переменной, а в строке.

Answer (score 2):

`index = a.find("Q")` - находит первую попавшуюся Q в строке, если не нашло, то возвращает -1.

Comment: А как сделать чтоб оно писало данную букву(cимвол)?

Comment: `print(a[index])`

Comment: @neon такое чувство что Вы не знаете что ищите) ничто Вам не мешает сделать `print('Q')`

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку задача так и непонятна, то приведу варианты, что тут можно найти:

- сам факт вхождения одной строки или символа в другую строку
- позицию, в которой найдено первое вхождение
- количество найденных вхождений

```
a = "1055Q999"
s = "Q"

if s in a:
    print(f'Символ/строка {repr(s)} найден(а) в строке {repr(a)}')
    print(f'Позиция первого вхождения: {a.find(s)}')
    print(f'Количество вхождений: {a.count(s)}')
```

Вывод:

```
Символ/строка 'Q' найден(а) в строке '1055Q999'
Позиция первого вхождения: 4
Количество вхождений: 1
```

При желании можно найти и все вхождения, если их много и они нас интересуют:

```
print(f'Все позиции вхождения: {", ".join(str(i) for i,x in enumerate(a) if x == s)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант где можно просто вывести id элемента в наборе (счет идет от нуля):

```
string = 'Добро пожаловать'
print("Поиск 'б' методом index:", string.index("б"))
```

Если надо вывести саму букву и ее позицию то можно вот так:

```
a = '234534K23432654'
number = 0
search = 'K'
errors = 0

for i in a:
    number += 1
    if i == search:
        answer = 'Нашел'
        print(answer, 'букву', search)
        print('Она на ' + str(number) + ' месте')
        break
    else:
        answer = 'Не нашел'
        print(answer, 'букву', search)
```

Comment: Т.к. number += 1 в обоих случаях - If и else - то лучше вынести за пределы этой логики, чтобы было только один раз.

Comment: number += 1 нужен в else т.к. алгоритм считает сколько циклов прошло до того как был найден искомый элемент, а в if нужен для того чтобы увеличить значение number на 1 когда элемент найден, что и будет указывать на порядковый номер знака в наборе. После чего делаем выход из цикла.

Comment: попробуйте еще с [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), не будет необходимости иметь счетчик, хотя в нем тоже нет ничего плохого.

Comment: @Old_Lamer я понимаю, для чего это нужно. Я говорю, что если в обеих ветках одно и то же действие, то его можно выполнять за пределами if-else, т.к. в любом случае надо выполнять, и от условия не зависит.